# Im not able to make Work RandomForest in R. It give me error on NA and also of predictor length

Tags: r, statistics, random-forest

I've a GEOdataset of biological data and actually my random forest model is not working
This is the code that is not working:

```
library("ALL")
library("genefilter")
library("randomForest")
library("GEOquery")

gse<- getGEO("GSE5060", destdir = ".", getGPL = FALSE)
dim(gse[[1]])
e.mat <- 2^(exprs(gse[[1]])[,c(20:40)])
dim(e.mat)
ffun <- filterfun(pOverA(0.20,100))
t.fil <- genefilter(e.mat,ffun)
t.fil
small.eset <- log2(e.mat[t.fil,])
dim(small.eset) 
group <- c(rep('B',10),rep('T',11)) # classification, in order
rf <- randomForest(x=t(small.eset), y=as.factor(group), ntree=100)
```

Comment: Please describe what the problem is, share code (not in screenshot format) and data and maybe someone will take time to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get to the hippy-machine-learning-predict-xyz , it makes sense to check the input, otherwise garbage-in garbage-out right?

If you do a summary of your predictors:

```
summary(small.eset)
   GSM101114        GSM101115         GSM101116         GSM114089    
 Min.   :  6.64   Min.   :  6.052   Min.   :  6.309   Min.   :  0.5  
 1st Qu.: 15.42   1st Qu.: 14.814   1st Qu.: 15.167   1st Qu.: 31.7  
 Median : 38.56   Median : 37.746   Median : 38.643   Median :116.9  
 Mean   :   Inf   Mean   :    Inf   Mean   :    Inf   Mean   :  Inf  
 3rd Qu.:152.05   3rd Qu.:158.972   3rd Qu.:156.699   3rd Qu.:503.9  
 Max.   :   Inf   Max.   :    Inf   Max.   :    Inf   Max.   :  Inf  
   GSM114090       GSM114091       GSM114092       GSM114093    
 Min.   :  0.2   Min.   :  0.7   Min.   :  0.4   Min.   :  0.3  
 1st Qu.: 30.3   1st Qu.: 51.0   1st Qu.: 40.5   1st Qu.: 38.7  
 Median :115.9   Median :175.3   Median :145.2   Median :136.2  
 Mean   :  Inf   Mean   :  Inf   Mean   :  Inf   Mean   :  Inf  
 3rd Qu.:510.9   3rd Qu.:555.2   3rd Qu.:515.9   3rd Qu.:546.1  
 Max.   :  Inf   Max.   :  Inf   Max.   :  Inf   Max.   :  Inf
```

That's a lot of Inf to deal with. And looking at the earlier steps,

```
e.mat <- 2^(exprs(gse[[1]])[,c(20:40)])
```

The values are already in some range from 0.1 to 1e5, if you take the 2 power of this, this will throw astronomical numbers.

You are using randomForest, one option is to just go ahead with model with the raw values, provided they are normalized:

```
x <- exprs(gse[[1]])[,c(20:40)]
# half of the samples are above 25% quantile
x <- x[rowMeans(x>quantile(x)[2]) > 0.5,]
x <- t(x)

y=as.factor(group)
rf <- randomForest(x=x, y=as.factor(group), ntree=100)
```

Or you can variance stablize the predictors:

```
library(vsn)
x <- exprs(gse[[1]])[,c(20:40)]
x <- x[rowMeans(x>quantile(x)[2]) > 0.5,]
fit = vsn2(x)
xnorm = predict(fit, x)
rf <- randomForest(x=t(xnorm), y=as.factor(group), ntree=100)
```

Comment: Thnx my friend this work, can you please explaine a bit better what you did with the line x <- x[rowMeans(x>quantile(x)[2]) >0.5,]

Comment: It's keeping on rows where at least half of the columns are more than than the .25 quantile of the whole matrix. It's a just a filter. U can use any other